# Why are some library routines implemented as macros simultaneously? Why is "va_arg" macro declared as a function (without "#define")?

Tags: c, function, macros, variadic-functions

I am struggling to put it clearly in words. So let me put it in parts. The contexts are from the C book by Mike Banahan (Links provided with each part below). Here are my questions as bullet points in bold:

- **Why are some library functions simultaneously implemented as macros too? What's the need? Here's what I read from the book [(Section 9.1.1)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/introduction.html):**

> A last general point is that many of the library routines may be
>   implemented as macros, provided that there will be no problems to do
>   with side-effects (as Chapter 7 describes). The Standard guarantees
>   that, if a function is normally implemented as a macro, there will
>   also be a true function provided to do the same job. To use the real
>   function, either undefine the macro name with *#undef*, or enclose its
>   name in parentheses, which ensures that it won't be treated as a
>   macro:

- ***va_start*, as we know it, is a function or macro? The following text from the book is the source of confusion as it implies both in the same breath, in adjacent lines!! [(Section 9.9)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)**

> Before any attempt can be made to access a variable argument list,
>   *va_start* must be called. It is defined as

```
 #include <stdarg.h>
void va_start(va_list ap, parmN);
```

> The *va_start* macro initializes ap for subsequent use by the functions
>   *va_arg* and *va_end*.

- **And finally, the most confusing part. In the following line, it's clearly written that *va_arg* is a macro and goes on to show how it is implemented. But how can a macro be implemented without a *#define* keyword, and that too with return type ('type') as if it were a function? [(Section 9.9)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)**

> Once initialized, the arguments supplied can be accessed sequentially
>   by means of the *va_arg* macro. This is peculiar because the type
>   returned is determined by an argument to the macro. Note that this is
>   impossible to implement as a true function, only as a macro. It is
>   defined as

```
#include <stdarg.h>
type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
```

Your answers will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The line of code you wrote supposedly defining `va_arg` is not the actual way it is defined.  That's just a function prototype that is written in documentation to explain how `va_arg` behaves for people who are familiar with looking at function prototypes, but actually the real definition of `va_arg` would have to use `#define`.

Comment: Here, I found some copy of stdarg.h on github and you can see what a real definition of va_arg looks like: https://github.com/DeforaOS/libc/blob/master/include/stdarg.h#L44-45

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes, that was helpful. It's declared as you said in line 44 of the link you gave.

Comment: Please don't ask two really distinct questions in one go. Too broad, voting to close.

Comment: `va_arg` may be a macro or a function, this depends on your system. Never rely on any of it.

Comment: When possible I like to provide both, with the #define overriding the prototype, though just as documentation and a means of giving Intellisense and similar tools a helping hand

Comment: @DavidGrayson it could use compiler magic instead of `#define`

Comment: You should probably make "Why are some functions implemented as macros" be a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are two distinct questions.

Firstly, `va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end` are guaranteed to be macros. `va_arg` cannot be a function, because its second argument is a type rather than a value.

As to why some functions are also macros: because you want a call to be inlined, making it fast, but you might also want to take its address and put that in a function pointer:

```
int (*function_pointer)(int, FILE *) = &(putc);
```

Comment: If **va_arg** is not a function, how come it is declared like one, that too without #define? How can the type of macros be explicitly declared just like return type of functions? That's my confusion...

Comment: @Thokchom: It's not. Your book is just misleading. What it means to say is that, in order for the macro to have well-defined behavior, its arguments must match what's documented by the fake function prototype, and the resulting value of the expression will have the type that the fake prototype implies.

Comment: The book author didn't make it up though; it comes from the libc docs:  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Macros.html#Argument-Macros

Comment: It's not really "misleading" or "fake"... it's **pseudocode**. It's what you *would* write in a higher-level language with types as legitimate objects.

Comment: Well, what was misleading in the book is that the author said "It is defined as" right before that line of code.  Maybe he should say "it behaves like a function which has this pseudocode prototype" or something.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thanks again for the new link. I too wondered initially because the authors have been very precise about everything in their book.BTW how you ran into that second link so soon?

Comment: You're welcome.  I searched Google for "libc" to find the project's home page and then clicked on "Documentation".